# Phonegap & Firebase Analytics

Tags: debugging, firebase, firebase-analytics, phonegap

Does anyone know how to implement Firebase Analytics in Phonegap app and test it? I have a basic "Hello world" app with the plugin installed

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I also have to mention I build my apps with Adobe Phonegap online. So I dont have Android Studio.Is it absolutely necesarely to build it in android studio in order to enable debugger ?

```
var settings = {
        developerModeEnabled: true
    };
    window.FirebasePlugin.setConfigSettings(settings);
    window.cordova.plugins.firebase.analytics.setEnabled(false);
    window.FirebasePlugin.setUserId("1");
    window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("select_content", {content_type: "page_view", item_id: "home"});
```

Comment: You are using phonegap. Which tool are you using with it? A raw notepad or something else (VS, Eclipse,..)?

Comment: Raw notepad. Notepad ++